# SwiftyJSON: can't get values

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swifty-json

I'm trying to get a JSON response from a PHP page and then use it with Swift. I'm using SwiftyJSON which seems quite simple, however I'm facing a strange issue.

My code is

```
let json = JSON(data: data!)
let name = json[0]["name"]
print(name)
```

this prints "null". However, if i try to print json[0], i get the object structure:

```
{"name":"Da Mario","description":"pizza","city":"12038 Savigliano","zip":"","address":"Via Macra","phone":"","lat":"44.6451515","lng":"7.6519596","permalink":"n-a"}
```

which seems ok to me. I really don't understand why printing json[0] works but json[0]["name"] doesn't.

Any idea? I really can't figure it out.

EDIT: this is the full json data:

```
[
  "{\"name\":\"Da Mario\",\"description\":\"pizza\",\"city\":\"12038 Savigliano\",\"zip\":\"\",\"address\":\"Via Macra\",\"phone\":\"\",\"lat\":\"44.6451515\",\"lng\":\"7.6519596\",\"permalink\":\"n-a\"}",
  "{\"name\":\"Burger Kebab\",\"description\":\"kebab\",\"city\":\"Savigliano\",\"zip\":\"12038\",\"address\":\"Via Trento\",\"phone\":\"\",\"lat\":\"44.6496363\",\"lng\":\"7.6525568\",\"permalink\":\"burgerkebab\"}"
]
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole json please? 
by doing print(json);

Comment: sure, I modified the question and added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some quotes in exceed.
Your json should looks like:

```
[
  {\"name\":\"Da Mario\",\"description\":\"pizza\",\"city\":\"12038 Savigliano\",\"zip\":\"\",\"address\":\"Via Macra\",\"phone\":\"\",\"lat\":\"44.6451515\",\"lng\":\"7.6519596\",\"permalink\":\"n-a\"},
  {\"name\":\"Burger Kebab\",\"description\":\"kebab\",\"city\":\"Savigliano\",\"zip\":\"12038\",\"address\":\"Via Trento\",\"phone\":\"\",\"lat\":\"44.6496363\",\"lng\":\"7.6525568\",\"permalink\":\"burgerkebab\"}
]
```

Currently you just have an array of string, With that you will have an array of object.